# wpf window at top while playing

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to topmost my window while its playing(audio/video)

I want to determine player is actually displaying.

Please help me.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="player" />
```

**Xaml:**

```
<CheckBox x:Name="allwaystop" Content="Always" Checked="allwaystop_Checked" />
<CheckBox x:Name="whileplaying" Content="While Playing" Checked="whileplaying_Checked"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="nevertop" Content="Never" IsChecked="True" Checked="nevertop_Checked" />
```

**Xaml.cs:**

```
private void allwaystop_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Always top
    Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
    parent.Topmost = true;           
}

private void whileplaying_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //WhilePlaying
    // What??
}

private void nevertop_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    //Never top
    Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
    parent.Topmost = false;
}
```

Please help me.

**Which code I will write inside the whileplaying checkbox code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think radio buttons are better suited for that purpose.

Second, you lucky I'm digging your project... here's more free code... There is room for improvement, though it will get you going. The following code implements a Player state tracker, and uses the tracker for various operations. You'll notice the tracker variable has been added to many of your methods so the Player state can be updated accordingly. This is probably similar to what @Bolu had in mind when he answered your question.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rdobtn_AlwaysTop" Content="Always top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="WindowZIndex" Checked="SetWindowZIndex"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rdobtn_TopWhilePlaying" Content="Top while playing" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="WindowZIndex" Checked="SetWindowZIndex"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rdobtn_LetUserPick" Content="Who cares" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="219,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="WindowZIndex" IsChecked="True" Checked="SetWindowZIndex" />

    public static bool IsMediaPlaying = false;//something to keep track of the player state

    private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayMedia();
    }

    public void PlayMedia()
    {
        if (IsMediaPlaying == false)
        {
            //nothing is playing
            if (mePlayer.Source == new Uri(playlist[listbox4.SelectedIndex].Filepath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
            {
                //nothing is playing, but the player already has the correct file loaded
                mePlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;//play it
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing is playing and the media player's loaded file(if any) is different than the selected file so play the selected file
                mePlayer.Source = new Uri(playlist[listbox4.SelectedIndex].Filepath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                mePlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
            }
        }
        else//something is already playing
        {
            if (mePlayer.Source == new Uri(playlist[listbox4.SelectedIndex].Filepath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
            {
                //the proper file is already playing
            }
            else
            {
                //something is playing but it looks like the user wants to play something different
                mePlayer.Source = new Uri(playlist[listbox4.SelectedIndex].Filepath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                mePlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
            }
        }
        IsMediaPlaying = true;
        SetWindowZIndex();
    }

    private void SetWindowZIndex(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetWindowZIndex();
    }

    private void SetWindowZIndex()
    {
        if (rdobtn_AlwaysTop.IsChecked == true)
        {
            Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
            parent.Topmost = true;
        }
        else if (rdobtn_TopWhilePlaying.IsChecked == true)
        {
            if (IsMediaPlaying == true)
            {
                Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
                parent.Topmost = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
                parent.Topmost = false;
            }
        }
        else if (rdobtn_LetUserPick.IsChecked == true)
        {
            Window parent = Window.GetWindow(this);
            parent.Topmost = false;
        }
    }

    private void mePlayer_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMediaPlaying = false;
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs1 = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent);  //Go to next
        button1.RaiseEvent(newEventArgs1);
    }

    private void mePlayer_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMediaPlaying = false;
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent);  //Go to next
        button1.RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    private void play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayMedia();
    }

    private void pause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mePlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Pause;
        IsMediaPlaying = false;
    }

    private void listbox4_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayMedia();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult, as there is no OnPlaying EventHandler or IsPlaying Property for `MediaElement`.

What you could do is:

1. Create a property `IsMediaPlaying` which will be updated by your `Play` `Pause` and `Stop` method.
2. In `whileplaying_Checked` EventHandler, check `IsMediaPlaying` and if it is true set `Topmost=true`;
3. In your start/play method, check if `whileplaying.IsChecked`, if it is true set the `Topmost = ture`. Set `IsMediaPlaying = true`
4. Also in your start/play method, subscribe to [`MediaElement.MediaEnded`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended(v=vs.110).aspx) Event and maybe also the [`MediaElement.MediaFailed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed(v=vs.110).aspx) Event.
   And in the `EventHandler` set `IsMediaPlaying=false` and check if `whileplaying.IsChecked`, when it is true set `Topmost = false`.
5. In `whileplaying_UnChecked` EventHandler, set `Topmost` according to other options. (i.e if `IsMediaPlaying` then set `Topmost=false`)

Comment: No this is not properly determine actually playing

Comment: @TaniaAkter, I agree, but since there is no OnPlaying EventHandler or IsPlaying Property as I said in my answer, I'm afraid there is no better way.

Comment: I agree with Bolu. Short of a built-in mechanism, you have to create and maintain your own. +1

Comment: @blaze_125 I am not understood

Comment: Actually, I think you are understood. You want to control the `Topmost` value based on `is the media player currently playing something?`. Though, as Bolu pointed out, there is no *out of the box* mechanism that keeps track of the media player state. Bolu suggested you build your own mechanism to keep track of the media player state and he supplied the core elements you would need to achieve such a thing. If we did not understand your question correctly, feel free to reformulate the question.